# Cookie issue in the site http://www.easybusinessregistration.com.au/

Tags: cookies, wordpress, session-cookies, gravity-forms-plugin

I have three forms here on this site http://www.easybusinessregistration.com.au/ for user to fill out.
But there is big cookie or cache issue for the site. Every time User need to clear their browser cookies and cache whenever I made any changes in the forms, site keeps on taking older form. This site is in wordpress and forms are created using gravity forms like http://www.easybusinessregistration.com.au/sole-trader-business-registration-formb/.

I am using same gravity form on other sites but there, forms are wroking fine but issue is with this site only.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with pages not refreshing after I had edited code, specifically CSS. I download the plugin "W3 Total Cache" and then you empty the cache in the general settings of the plugin whenever you edit code. It's good practice to do so every time you download or delete a plugin also.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out by using below php code:
    header ("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time())." GMT");
    header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");